# Memory error for decision tree with 66k features, using scikit python packages

Tags: python, out-of-memory, tokenize, sparse-matrix, decision-tree

**Problem Statement**

I am using a document of 1600000 lines and ~66k features.
I am using the bag of words approach to build a decision tree.
Following code is working fine for 1000 line document.
But throws memory error for the actual 1600000 line document.
My Server has a 64GB of RAM.

Instead of using `.todense()` or `.toarray()`, is there any way to use the sparse matrix directly ? OR
Is there any options to reduce the default type float64?
Kindly help me on this.

**Code:**

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, max_df=0.5,stop_words='english')
X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train.todense(),corpus2)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 103, in <module>
    clf = clf.fit(X_train.todense(),corpus2)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 458, in todense
    return np.asmatrix(self.toarray())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py", line 550, in toarray
    return self.tocoo(copy=False).toarray()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 219, in toarray
    B = np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype)
MemoryError
```

**In short, is there any methods to use classification tree for large data set with 66k features.?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add dtype=np.float32 eg: vec = TfidfVectorizer(..., dtype=np.float32)

As for sparse/dense I have similar problem.
GradientBoostingClassifier, RandomForestClassifier or DecisionTreeClassifier need dense data, for that reason I use SVC.